# Getting TermSet for a different locale using JSOM

Tags: managed-metadata, client-object-model, term-store, multilingual

I'm trying to pull back the labels from a term store for a different locale in SharePoint Online. So I have installed the different language packs in the term store:

[image]

And then I have added a TermSet named "Test" with the label "Test 1" in English and "Hungarian 1" in Hungarian. Good Hungarian translation, dont you think?

So now from JSOM I would like to pull back Hungarian 1. This seems simple enough on paper. But in practice doesnt work. So my JSOM code is:

```
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var taxonomySession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
var termStore = taxonomySession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
var termSets = termStore.getTermSetsByName("Test", "1038"); //tried this with an int instead of a string as well

context.load(taxonomySession);
context.load(termStore);
context.load(termSets);

context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {

var termSetsEnumerator = termSets.getEnumerator();

while(termSetsEnumerator.moveNext())
{
    getTermSets(termSetsEnumerator, context, success, error);
}

}), Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
    errorCallback('Error: ' + args.get_message());
}));
```

Unless I provide the LCID for English 1033 I dont get any termsets back. Am I doing something wrong? I can see one other individual has had this problem and the suggested solution works but it means doing an executeQueryAsync for EVERY term by using this code:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();         
var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);  
var termDefaultValue = taxSession.getTerm(termId).getDefaultLabel(lcid);
context.executeQueryAsync(function() {
  success(termDefaultValue);
},
failure);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098072/reading-sharepoint-taxonomy-term-store-and-getdefaultlabellcid

This surely cannot be right? There must be a way of getting all the terms in 1 language in a bulk collect? The above solution is not viable when you're trying to build a term tree in a different language.

**Edit**

To show was I mean about what value I expect to get back in English I may have set this value for the label:

[image]

But then in (for example) Danish I have Danish on the end, when I pull back the term set name for the Danish LCID and drill into the terms I'd expect to get this label (Test 2 Term Danish), instead I still get the English version of the term (Test 2 Term):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically it depends on the following settings:

- a `Default Language` of Term Store
- selected language while creating Term Set

Assume English(1033), Finnish(1035) and Russian(1049) languages are installed and  the following code is used for retrieving term sets:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();         
var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(ctx);  
var termStore = taxSession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();

var termSets = termStore.getTermSetsByName("Document Type",1033);  //Default Language
var termSetsRU = termStore.getTermSetsByName("Document Type",1049);
var termSetsFI = termStore.getTermSetsByName("Document Type",1035);
ctx.load(termSets);
ctx.load(termSetsRU);
ctx.load(termSetsFI);


ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
            console.log(String.format('TermSet for default(English) language {0}',termSets.get_count() > 0 ? 'found' : 'not found'));
            console.log(String.format('TermSet for Finnish language {0}',termSetsFI.get_count() > 0 ? 'found' : 'not found'));
            console.log(String.format('TermSet for Russian language {0}',termSetsRU.get_count() > 0 ? 'found' : 'not found'));
        },
        function(sender,args){
            console.log(args.get_message());
        });
```

**Results**

Assume the *default language* for term store is set to 1033 and we need to create a Term Set named `Document Type`

**Example 1**

Selected language: `English`

Output:

```
TermSet for default(EN) language found
TermSet for RU language not found
TermSet for FI language not found
```

**Example 2**

Selected language: `Finnish`

Output:

```
TermSet for default(EN) language found
TermSet for RU language not found
TermSet for FI language found
```

To summarize:

- in order to retrieve **all** available term sets specify a default
  language for [SP.Taxonomy.TermStore.getTermSetsByName method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn269605%28v=office.15%29.aspx)
- when *non-default* language is specified for
  [SP.Taxonomy.TermStore.getTermSetsByName method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn269605%28v=office.15%29.aspx), only term sets
  created for this language will be returned

**Update: How to load single Term with Labels info**

The following example demonstrates how to:

- retrieve Term with Labels
- print default labels for a Term

Example:

```
function loadTermWithLabels(termId,success,error)
{
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();         
    var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(ctx);  
    var termStore = taxSession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
    var term = termStore.getTerm(termId);  
    ctx.load(term,'Labels');

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
            success(term);
        },
        error);
}


var termId = "term id goes here";
loadTermWithLabels(termId,
    function(term){
        //print default labels
        var labels = term.get_labels(); 
        for(var j = 0; j < labels.get_count();j++){
            var label = labels.getItemAtIndex(j);  
            if(label.get_isDefaultForLanguage()){  /* Is default label? */
                switch(label.get_language()){
                    case 1033:
                       console.log(String.format('Label for EN language: {0}',label.get_value()));
                       break;
                    case 1049:
                       console.log(String.format('Label for RU language: {0}',label.get_value()));
                       break;
                    case 1035:
                       console.log(String.format('Label for FI language: {0}',label.get_value()));
                       break;      
                }
            }
        }    
    },
    function(sender,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
    }
);
```

**Update 2: how to load multiple terms with Labels info**

The following example demonstrates how to load all the terms in Term Set with Labels info:

```
function loadTermsWithLabels(termSetId,success,error)
{
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();         
    var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(ctx);  
    var termStore = taxSession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
    var termSet = termStore.getTermSet(termSetId);
    var terms = termSet.getAllTerms();  
    ctx.load(terms,'Include(Name,Labels)');
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
            success(terms);
        },
        error);
}


var termSetId = "e8c3e26c-e559-4916-a40c-c8087b236836";
loadTermsWithLabels(termSetId,
  function(terms){
     for(var i = 0; i < terms.get_count();i++){
        var term = terms.getItemAtIndex(i);    
        console.log(String.format('Term : {0}',term.get_name()));
        //print labels
        var labels = term.get_labels(); 
        for(var j = 0; j < labels.get_count();j++){
            var label = labels.getItemAtIndex(j);  
            if(label.get_isDefaultForLanguage()){  /* Is default label? */
                switch(label.get_language()){
                    case 1033:
                       console.log(String.format('Label for EN language: {0}',label.get_value()));
                       break;
                    case 1049:
                       console.log(String.format('Label for RU language: {0}',label.get_value()));
                       break;
                    case 1035:
                       console.log(String.format('Label for FI language: {0}',label.get_value()));
                       break;      
                }
            }
        }
     }       
  },
  function(sender,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
  }
);
```

Comment: Hi Vadim, Thank you for the reply. The code you put above gets a count for me too but if you then dig into that term set and pull out the terms name the label is still the English version, even though I have added a Finish label. So in your example I'll still get back "Test 1" from both termSets and termSetsFI when I drill down into the terms within those term sets. Also should the language selected when creating the term set make a difference? As if I created a "Test" term set in English and switch to Finish it will be there as "Test" as well, I cant create that term set in another language.

Comment: I've edited my answer to try and be a bit clearer about what I'd expect to get back, with your solution when you dig into the term sets do you get the correct label for the LCID you specified when you did the call to getTermSetsByName? As thats where the problem is for me.

Comment: Thanks, with screenshot it became a bit clearer, at least right now i could see you actually need to retrieve terms (not term sets) properties (like labels).. will update my answer

Comment: The answer has been updated

Comment: Hi Vadim, Thanks for updating your answer. It was your answer that was in my original post which uses ctx.executeQueryAsync. The problem I have with this is that if you're trying to build a term tree in a different language that could have 100+ terms thats 100+ call backs to SharePoint with each executeQueryAsync. I'm surprised there isnt a way to get all the labels back in 1 call to save having to do this. But I appreciate you taking the time to propose this answer, thank you.

Comment: Hi, the answer has been updated, see the section: Update 2. The example demonstrates how to load multiple terms with labels using a single request to the server

Comment: Genius :-) I can see Include() being extremely useful in the future. Bit odd how MS own documentation doesnt mention this Include option http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn168903%28v=office.15%29.aspx. Thank you for your help, marked as answer.

Comment: Great! Indeed, I've also not found any explanation of syntax for SP.ClientContext.load method in MSDN